# Alternative pattern to Sync Until Successful flow

Tags: mule

Just read that until successful doesn't support synchronous calls.
http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6145?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel#issue-tabs

Whats the alternate pattern to accomplish it ?

Do I have to use request-reply or is there a better way to do it ?

Answer (score 2):

A synchronous until-successful like pattern can be implemented using a combination of the [request-reply router](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Routing+Message+Processors#RoutingMessageProcessors-RequestReply) and a transactional flow staring with a vm inbound endpoints.

This way until the transaction will be committed or the timeout of the router kicks in, the message will be redelivered

Answer (score 0):

The `util-successful` router can be sync now. Try Mule 3.5.0-M4.